# $_POST can pass data in localhost, but not in live server

Tags: php, html, forms

I really tried to figure out this problem but did not success. In my website, I have 2 basic forms. One for log in and one for registration. When I was testing the code in Apache, it was working wonderful. The forms can pass the inputs to another php page and perform checks. But when I moved the code to a hosting server, the form could not pass any data (I made sure I typed in those fields.) I really ran out of ideas what I have done wrong. The PHP version in Apache is 5.4.7, and the php version in hosting is 5.2.17. Below is the code of the forms:

```
<form action="register_check.php" method="post" style="text-align:center">
    <input type="text" name="username" class="form-control" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Username"/>     
    <input type="password" name="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password"/>
    <input type="password" name="password_again" class="form-control" placeholder="Please type the password again"/>
    <input type="text" name="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Email"/><br/>
    <input type="hidden" name="token" value="">
    <input type="submit" name="register" class="btn btn-primary"/>
</form>

<form action="login_check.php" method="post" style="text-align:center">
    <input type="text" name="username" class="form-control" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Username"/>
    <input type="password" name="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password"/>
    <input type="hidden" name="token" value="">
    <label 
            <input type="checkbox" name="remember" id="remember"> Remember Me 
    </label>

    <input type="submit" name="login" class="btn btn-primary"/>
</form>
```

When I was testing in Apache locally, the data could successfully pass to register_check.php or login_check.php depends on which button I pressed. To make sure the data was able to pass through, I wrote this on both register_check.php and login_check.php:

```
var_dump($_POST);
die();
```

Even when I typed nothing into the fields, I got an array back:

> array(6) { ["username"]=> string(0) "" ["password"]=> string(0) "" ["password_again"]=> string(0) "" ["email"]=> string(0) "" ["token"]=> string(0) "" ["register"]=> string(6) "Submit" }

But now my headache begins. I moved the exactly same code to my hosting server. I typed nothing in the form, and pressed submit. The var_dump gave me back this result:

> array(0) { }

and even when I typed something into the input fields, it still gave me back the same result:

> array(0) { }

I really ran out of ideas what could have went wrong. Before I was suspecting the php version 5.2.17 might be too old, but to me that is kinda impossible cause this is just a form processing.

So I hope somebody can tell me what is wrong. I couldn't sleep because of this weird problem. Thank you so much!

Comment: this code works for me

Comment: Try changing the `action` attribute to `/register_check.php` and `/login_check.php` and see  if that helps.

Comment: no, not working even I added the /. Thanks though

Comment: please check your serve configuration via phpinfo(); function on your server.

Comment: maybe its not the form but the php code that handles the `$_POST` data, post the relevant php code too. also are there any errors in the  logs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is there a `.htaccess` on your live server? If yes, try to delete it and send your data again.

Comment: Thank you so much. It is working now. I was trying to solve this problem by myself, and spent 5 hours looking at the codes. Still hard to believe deleting .htaccess solves everything. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Check the configuration of your live Server. Apache is basicially configured to be used for Development, so almost everything is enabled. Maybe your Live Server has an essential function blocked.

Comment: Thank you so much. I think you are right. The configuration in .htaccess was different than the one in Apache. I deleted .htaccess and that solved the problem. Thank you once again.